# Нагрузочное тестирование

Tags: java, python, любой-язык, нагрузочное-тестирование

Увидел в интеренете [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-aBOgz68UE), в котором тестируют скорость работы `spring`. Я новичек в программировании. Что это за программа на видео и как я могу у себя провести такие же тесты ? Что мне для этого надо нагуглить ?
 Я же так смогу тестировать не сколько java-сервера, но и любые другие (например, `python`) ?

Comment: В этом видео человек, на самом деле, провел нагрузочное тестирование серверов, а не фреймворки. Но он, видимо, об этом не догадывается.

Comment: Ну а что за программа ? Как я могу сделать так же ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для нагрузочного тестирования могу посоветовать [yandex tank](https://tech.yandex.ru/tank/), [apache jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Comment: Хотелось бы знать чем они отличаются и в каких случая, что лучше использовать..

Comment: Jmeter имеет удобный и понятный ui, довольно распространен и на любые непонятные вопросы легко можно нагуглить ответ. По поводу танка, честно, ничего сказать не могу. Его я не использовал, но слышал много положительных отзывов.

Answer (score 4):

Программа называется `Apache Benchmark`. Для того, чтобы установить ее необходимо выполнить следующие команды (debian):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
sudo gem install sinatra --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

А дальше уже пользоваться как на видео.

Answer (score 4):

Советую сначала ответить на вопрос "зачем?". Серьёзно, если вы - новичок, вам это не только не нужно, но даже вредно. Вы представляете что вы хотите измерять? Тестировать под нагрузкой имеет смысл только комплекс "приложение+внешнее окружение". Всё остальное - замеры абстрактного сферического коня в вакууме.

Comment: Понятно, что новичку это совсем ни к чему, но не стоит забывать, что данный сайт является базой знаний и подобные вопросы могут возникать у многих людей.

Comment: В таком случае вот главное знание: **Любой тест производительности в отрыве от реальных данных и окружения является пустой тратой времени.**
А в видео используется "программа" Apache Benchmark, ознакомиться с которой можно [по ссылке](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html)